# Good examples for simple in-app purchases?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Can anyone point me to very simple, but concrete (non-abstract) demos for implementations of in-app purchases via Google Play?

I found a few ones dating back to 2012, but to stay up to date, I would prefer to use the later libraries (afaik com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.1). My problem is that the sample "Taxi" demos provided by Google are way too massive, for my previous in-app code (simply purchasing a license and then storing a key locally) 3 or 4 functions in a single file were enough - basically consisting of involving the Google Play purchase process and then returning the status (successful or not).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use this one library: [Checkout (Android In-App Billing Library)](https://github.com/serso/android-checkout)

It is fast, secure, and easier to use.